# How to override the default select option css?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

In a form, I have two different dropdown menus (one required and one not required).

The required dropdown select has lightgrey placeholder text color whereas the regular dropdown select has black placeholder text color.

I want to override the black placeholder color to match the lightgrey. I cannot seem to override it with `!important` in CSS

```
select option:disabled {
   color: lighgrey !important;
}
```

This doesn't work and I'm not sure what works

Answer (score 1):

place the color on select

```css
select:disabled  {
   color: lightgrey!important;
}
```

```html
<select disabled>
<option>black</option>
<option>green</option>
</select>
```